# Не переведён пункт "Company Alerts" в настройках профиля

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, настройки-профиля

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current

> [image: настройки профиля]

1. Company Alerts.
2. Content from companies you follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Утвердил предложения от [MSDN.WhiteKnight](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/240512/msdn-whiteknight):

1. https://ru.traducir.win/string/13035

   > Уведомления компаний
2. https://ru.traducir.win/string/13037

   > Содержимое от компаний, которые вы отслеживаете

Появятся с новой версией движка.

Comment: *Содержимое от компаний* – это как-то не по-русски звучит. Может как-то типа *Материалы компаний ...* обозвать?

Comment: @АндрейNOP я бы назвал "контент".

Comment: @АндрейNOP можно отдельный вопрос с предложением задать)